# TRIO Lib queue get and put

Tags: python-3.x, python-trio

Hello I'm trying to use trio with two asyncronous functions and a message in between. but it doesn't launch the consumer and I don't really understand why . The producer sends well in the'queue' and does not send anything once it is saturated. But the consumer doesn't go for it. Or am I making a mistake?  Thank you in advance

```
import time

import trio
async def producer(queue):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if queue.full() is False:
            queue.put_nowait(1)
            print(queue.full())
            print('put')

async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        if queue.full() is True:
            print(queue.get_nowait())
            print(queue.full())
        print('get')

async def main():

    queue = trio.Queue(capacity=4)
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        # Two producers
        nursery.start_soon(consumer, queue)
        nursery.start_soon(producer, queue)

trio.run(main)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `time.sleep`. If you replace both of the calls to `time.sleep(...)` with calls to `await trio.sleep(...)`, then your example works.

Trio, like all async libraries, can only switch between tasks at places where you use `await`. This means that you should never use blocking synchronous functions like `time.sleep` – instead you need to use the asynchronous versions that Trio provides, like `trio.sleep`. In your code, you don't have any `await`s at all, so whichever task happens to run first will keep running forever, and never give the other task a chance to run.

The [Trio tutorial has more details on this](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#async-functions).

It is unfortunate that Trio doesn't notice this and give you some kind of warning... I just [filed an issue](https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/591) to hopefully add that.

Also, FYI, your way of working with the queue is probably making things more complicated than they need to be :-). I don't think I ever use `queue.full()`, and `put_nowait` and `get_nowait` have some legitimate uses but they're fairly rare. For most purposes, the only things you need to call are `await queue.put(value)` and `value = await queue.get()` (or `print(await queue.get())`, or whatever).